# phpMyAdmin inserting repeated queries

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to phpMyAdmin please someone help.
I have an multidimensional array in php and am trying to insert information into my database, but for some reason the information gets repeated. For example if i only have three person's info on my array the database will insert 5 people repeating some. The program executes more queries than it should. I don't know if this has to do with phpMyAdmin or just my php code.

```
require("connect_db.php");
foreach($alumni as $alum){


//firstName and lastName must exist since they are required fields.
$first_name= $alum['firstName'];
$last_name= $alum['lastName'];

//check if the alum has provided a summary.
if (array_key_exists('summary', $alum)){
    $summary= $alum['summary'];
}else{
    $summary= "No summary available";
}

//check if the alum has provided a headline.
if (array_key_exists('headline', $alum)){
    $headline= $alum['headline'];
}else{
    $headline= "No headline available";
}

//check if the alum has provided a picture.
if (array_key_exists('pictureUrl', $alum)){
    $picture= $alum['pictureUrl'];
}else{
    $picture= "No picture available";
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO profile    VALUE('','$first_name','$last_name','$headline','$summary', '$picture')");
//echo $first_name." ". $last_name." ".$headline." ".$summary;
}
mysql_close($link);
```

the table looks something like this:

```
ID  firstname  lastname  headline  summary  pictureURL
----------------------------------------------------
1    Jane       Smith     Student   blah      blah
-----------------------------------------------------
2    Jane       Smith     Student   blah      blah
-------------------------------------------------------
3    John       Doe       Student   blah      blah
--------------------------------------------------------
4    Jake       Jacobs    Student   blah      blah
-----------------------------------------------------
5    John       Doe       Student   blah      blah
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you get the $alumni variable? Maybe the source has duplicates?

Comment: it all depends upon the foreach loop you are using and secondly change VALUE to VALUES in mysql_query.

Comment: `INSERT INTO profile VALUES`

Comment: @khattam I checked $alumni using print_r but I do not see any duplicates. $alumni comes from another file. I used JSON.stringify(alumni) then in the above file $alumni = json_decode($_POST['alum'], true);

Comment: @MAZ Iqbal I changed VALUE to VALUES and it continues to do the same. How is the foreach loop affecting it? If in the above example it should only loop three times

Comment: are you still facing the issue??

Comment: @MazIqbal I figured out what the problem is. I used a loop to send information to this file and I could only see the last $alumni array that got sent. Here is the problem in another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391058/sending-javascript-global-variables-after-being-modified-in-function-call)